# Product inventory with multiple attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table of products I have a field representing an attributeset.

The attributeset is a collection of attributes (size, color, etc).

Each attribute has several values such as blue, green, red etc.

How would I go about storing inventory information for products with multiple (and not fixed amount of) attributes?

Comment: I guess I could set a limit of 3 attributes per attributeset, and have inventory table look like this: (product_id, attribute1value, attribute2value, attribute3value, itemsinstock). That might be the easiest option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest instead of breaking NF1 use [Entity Value Attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model. This is not without its problems as well. The wikipedia article explains this and includes alternatives including using sparse columns or XML strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
products
--------
id
name

attributes
----------
id
name
value

product_attributes
------------------
id
product_id
attribute_id
```

Or

```
products
--------
id
name

attributes
----------
id
name

product_attributes
------------------
id
product_id
attribute_id
value


SELECT * FROM products,
 (SELECT * FROM product_attributes LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = 
 product_attributes.product_id) AS prod_attr
LEFT JOIN attributes ON prod_attr.attribute_id = attributes.id
```

Comment: I have tables set up for everything you are describing. I am looking for the best solution to keep track of inventory when a product has multiple attributes.

Comment: Maybe you could you explain with an example? This schema allows a product to have as many attribute as you wish.

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep track of inventory on the products, based on their attributes. Say 5 green XL t-shirts, 7 blue Small t-shirts. However I don't know which or how many attributes each product will have.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between Products and Attributes in a relational database by introducing a "[junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)" (here called ProductAttribute) to hold [associative entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities):

```
Product  <--one-to-many-->  ProductAttribute  <--many-to-one-->  Attribute
--------                    ----------------                     ---------
PK: id                      PK: id                               PK: id
    name                    FK: product_id                           name
                            FK: attribute_id
```